# Use the same database in Django and C++

Tags: c++, database, django

I'm looking for a way to use the same database backend in both Django and C++. I've searched on the Internet, but couldn't found much information. What I need is to make some inserts in the database from a C++ application and use django for displaying some collected data. It would be mostly a simple demo application.

It would be ideal if I could use an ORM in C++ instead of raw queries. I want to maintain portability with different database backends. I imagine this should work by defining the database models for both applications.

Is there any library which can help me with this ? I've found something called [QDjango](https://github.com/jlaine/qdjango/), but nowhere in the documentation is mentioned if such a thing is possible.

Comment: I don't see why not... Just use the proper bindings for the database system you are using, and be sure to connect to the same database... What is it you are having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

There're some ORM classes for C++, like this one: http://www.qxorm.com/qxorm_en/quick_sample.html

You just need to follow the same name conventions used in Django.
Table name example: myapp_tablename, id as pk, and so on.